# Detecting end of the line in file stored in string variable

Tags: php, parsing

Here's the file I happen to analyze through php:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "subdir/file.h"

#define STRUCT_PTR struct {int i;} *

// This function does nothing useful.
int func(int i, ...) {
    return i + i;
}

/*
    + + + + + + Main. + + + + + + + + +
*/
int main(void) {
    int i = 1;
    char s[10] = "- - - -";

    i++;
    s[1] = 'b';
    i += func(4);

    STRUCT_PTR t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    if (!t) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    t->i = 1 == 2 ? 3 : -5;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// zZ
```

After the last line-commentary there's end of file. Respectively, when I open it with and editor, there's not new empty line after that commentary.

I store the content of this file to variable, like this `$var = file_get_contents(path-to-file.c)`.

Then I cycle it through:

```
for($i = 0; isset($fileContent[$i]); $i++)
```

And I count characters in commentaries, including `"//", "/*", "*/"`, and I do also count end of the line character.
Expected result is 89 and I am still getting only 88. I am pretty sure that this is because I am unable to detect end of the line, when there's no new line following.

I test it like this `if($fileContent[$i]==PHP_EOL)`, but I have also tried using different combos using \n, \r\n, etc.

Thank you for your help in advance!

**EDIT:
More of my code**

```
for($i = 0; isset($fileContent[$i]); $i++)
                {

// ... some not so important conditions


                    if($fileContent[$i] == '/' && !$inComment && !$inBComment)
                    {
                        if($fileContent[$i+1] == '/')
                        {
                            $inComment = true;
                            $charCount += 2;
                            $skip = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if($inComment)
                    {

                        if($fileContent[$i] == PHP_EOL)
                        {
                            $charCount++;
                            $inComment = false; 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $charCount++;
                        }

                        continue; 

                    }
```

Comment: Please show us your full code! (So you want to could all comments in this file?)

Comment: @Rizier123 Full code is pretty long, I'll add just the part where I work with line-commentaries, as that is the only place where it does not work as tested and supposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the contents of every line do this. This one liner should do it for you. Note that this is only valid for one line comments.

```
<?php

//load file into array
$fileContents = file('test.txt');

//init counter
$charCount = 0;

foreach ($fileContents as $fileContent)
{
    //+count
    $charCount +=  (strpos(trim($fileContent),'//') === 0 )?strlen($fileContent):0;
}

//print
echo $charCount;

?>
```

Comment: This actually prints out number 42, but 44 is expected in this case. From my point of view it completely ignores line ending, which is exactly opposite of what I need. But thank you for trying.

Comment: It's because I was trimming the string so it doesn't count the space at the beginning of the comment. I updated it so it does. You should get 44 now.

Comment: in the end not the exact solution, I wanted to use, but it solves the problem. Thank you, and marking this as answered.